# Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed |Excel|VBA|

Tags: excel, vba

Error : Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
For Each Ws In Sheets(Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"))

    Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count).Replace What:="AP", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
    Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count).Replace What:="BL", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
    Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count).Replace What:="MA", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
    Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count).Replace What:="PA", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
    Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count).Replace What:="PL", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
    Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count).Replace What:="SL", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
    Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count).Replace What:="UP", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole

    Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count).Replace What:="H1", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
    Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count).Replace What:="H2", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
    Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count).Replace What:="TR", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
    Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count).Replace What:="WH", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
    Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count).Replace What:="NJ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
    Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count).Replace What:="AL", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
    Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count).Replace What:="SUP", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole

Next Ws
```

**If match is Found in each sheet the Data is Been Cleared => have Conditional Formatting in Range => I to AM**

This is my another code which i have tried not working

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, c As Range
For Each Ws In Sheets(Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"))
    lr = Ws.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    For Each c In Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & lr)
        Select Case UCase(c.Value)
            Case "SUP", "AP", "AL"
                c.Value = ""
                c.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End Select
    Next
Next Ws
```

This is the Image of my Excel

[my image][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDLj4.png

This Below Works fine for me But not setting the cell color to normal cell color like no fill color

```
'what:=UCase("SUP"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=True

Dim Ws As Worksheet
For Each Ws In Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))

Ws.Range("A4:K" & Rows.Count).Replace what:=UCase("SUP"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=True
Ws.Range("A4:K" & Rows.Count).Replace what:=UCase("SUP"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=False

Ws.Range("A4:K" & Rows.Count).Replace what:=UCase("AP"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=True
Ws.Range("A4:K" & Rows.Count).Replace what:=UCase("AP"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=False

Ws.Range("A4:K" & Rows.Count).Replace what:=UCase("AL"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=True
Ws.Range("A4:K" & Rows.Count).Replace what:=UCase("AL"), Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=False

Next Ws
```

this is below output of above code
[output][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H09ab.png

Comment: `Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & Rows.Count)` is `Ws.Range("I9:AM681048576")`, which is an invalid range since column `AM` will never have 68 more rows than `Rows.Count`.Remove that `68`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - You mean 680 *million* more rows than `Rows.Count`.  :O

Comment: @BruceWayne *cough* uhm, yes, of course :)

Comment: Be aware that `Rows.Count` refers to the `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count`, and not the count of the rows of the sheets your are looping through.

Comment: @DarXyde - Does that matter when using `Rows.Count`, as that number should be the same no matter the sheet.  (Or perhaps does it affect speed of the macro in a small way?)

Comment: The error you are getting is because you are trying to loop through sheets you don't have, according to your image. @BruceWayne you are correct, but still... worth mentioning.

Comment: i have tried this code also updated the question have a look @BruceWayne

Comment: Ya the Range which i am showing their is I:AM => this is from my actual project on which i am working => so i shown my scenario with the above example => if anyone code help me out with the this issue

Comment: What error are you getting? You could instead just do a broad find/replace, then conditional format the empty cells to have no fill?  Also, unless you have hidden rows, again you should remove the `68` from your `Ws.Range("I9:AM68" & lr)` range.

Comment: @BruceWayne => this is my actual image => [my image][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDLj4.png => suggest me what need to change to make it work

Comment: @Bruce there's an edge case where an unqualified Rows can matter: when the referenced wb and the active wb are different types, xls vs xlsx/m.  IMHO always qualify, it's very little effort and ever so slightly faster to run

Comment: @chrisneilsen - Agreed it's better to qualify (I always do anyways) - I was just wondering if it's totally necessary but good call with the xlsx/m difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to get the last row in that range, and not the actual `rows.count`, see below one way to achieve those replacements.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub doSomeReplacements()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook   'set your workbook variable
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim shNames() As String: shNames = Split("Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3", ",") 'allocate sheet names to an array
    Dim strReplaces() As String: strReplaces = Split("AP,BL,MA,PA,PL,SL,UP,H1,H2,TR,WH,NJ,AL,SUP", ",") 'allocate replacement strings to an array
    Dim lastRow As Long, X As Long, Z As Long, R As Long, C As Long

    For X = LBound(shNames) To UBound(shNames)  'Loop through the array of sheet names
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Ws = wb.Sheets(shNames(X))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not Ws Is Nothing Then   'If there is a worksheet to work with....
            With Ws
                'lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row   'get last row at column "I"
                lastRow = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 'alternative last row

                For R = 1 To lastRow
                    For C = 1 To 11 '"A:K"
                        For Z = LBound(strReplaces) To UBound(strReplaces) 'Loop through the array of replacements and apply the replacement
                            With .Cells(R, C)
                                If .Value = strReplaces(Z) Then
                                    .Value = ""
                                    .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                                End If
                            End With
                        Next Z
                    Next C
                Next R
            End With
        End If
        Set Ws = Nothing
    Next X

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: => i tried your code => not cleared anything => My Range Starts from I9 :AM9  till I68:AM68

Comment: Are you using the code in the correct workbook? Otherwise change the workbook variable, see updated code.

Comment: You can use `ActiveWorkbook` or `Workbooks("workbook name.xlsx")`

Comment: see on button click all the sheets from jan - dec should get clear the data => i have button in sheet1 => when i button click in sheet 1 => then remaning sheets jan dec should get cleared  @DarXyde

Comment: What you are trying to do above is different than `clear`ing the sheets. There are shorter/better ways to clear the sheets than do replacements. Unfortunately if you are unable to use the above code, you should try to folow a VBA course online (there are countless), on how to do some basic VBA coding.

Comment: i have tried one code which works for me => only one issue code you my updated question => last code => it clears all the matching but not set the cell color to normal cell color => no fill color  @DarXyde

Comment: => can you explain what it is => For R = 9 To lastRow
                    For C = 9 To 39 '"I:AM"   => can you show it for this image  => https://paste.pics/114cb60a9ba41d55a155c4f86834644b

Comment: For each row starting with row 9, for each column from I to AM... As suggested before, have a read of some basic VBA .

Comment: your code works as expected but it as flaw in it ... see this output 1 https://paste.pics/e61a12dc72f2b41d301f86f3556eee26    => it detects the last row used of Column A is A7 => Upto that Rows all the Data is empty ...after clicking the button => this is output i am getting  https://paste.pics/dfa1fcf54981542ef70892b11ec281eb  ....i have purposefully highlighted with orange color to show you that it erase only that rows ? what about the Below rows SUP in it .

Comment: But my question is if the  column A is empty Does not have any Data filled in it then your code fail to work ... see this output also  when i click on the Button =>
 https://paste.pics/36cfa360c2013648d6a96095c5319f75  => Please Update the Code ...

Comment: see i have changed here values in code to work with demo Data                 lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   'get last row at column "I"
                For R = 1 To lastRow
                    For C = 1 To 11 '"A:K"   => Your code fails to do so...

Comment: Based on your code, I'm checking for the last row in column `I`... based on your screenshots, i believe you've changed that part to check column `A` instead.

Comment: this is my Demo Excel where worked .... please do download 100% safe  https://www.sendspace.com/file/h63g56  => see code on Button which is your above code

Comment: So you changed the code in a way that won't work, and then say my code doesn't? Now that doesn't make much sense, is it? Change `lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row` to `lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count`, see if that works better for you.

Comment: @ DarXyde my friend yaa ... i am working on project were i am tracking the Leaves of Employee => like AL => Approved leave , BL => block leave , SUP => support leave => so i am marking the day on which they have taken leave

Comment: lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   'get last row at column "I"

                For R = 1 To lastRow
                    For C = 1 To 11 '"A:K"  ... this is what i have changed .. sorry i send wrong one above code

Comment: are you targeting only row 1 and checking for used column

Comment: Have you tried the last updated code? It does work fine on the spreadsheet you've gave in the link.

Comment: last one is not getting deleted .... lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
                For R = 1 To lastRow
                    For C = 1 To 11 '"A:K"    => output => https://paste.pics/b9063867ca755a3b94b1fc3859ed76a4  => Can you please modify over all code works perfect

Comment: See updated code, that should be fine now, even if you have an empty row at the top of your data for no reason.

Comment: Thanks Bro ... you are amazing works perfectly ... sorry if i hurt you then ;)